# 0 Call to a member function getState() on bool in search bar

Tags: search, joomla-3.9

As per mentioned in subject, my website is generating the following error when the user fails to search with a keyword:

> 0 Call to a member function getState() on bool in search bar.

Can anyone please advise me on this?

[image]p[image]

Comment: The error means that somewhere loading a model failed. Enable Debug in Global Configuration and post stack trace.

Comment: @ummul Welcome to JSE.  Please take our [tour].

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a Yootheme template to me and I've experienced similar errors when updating Yootheme Pro when I've had a template override in place.

You might want to check if there's a template override for the search results page and if there is, try disabling to see if it fixes the error.

Comment: Here's a familiar face!  Welcome to JSE and thank you for contributing.  Please take the [tour].  You may be dead right about this being a Yootheme template, but it would be better to ask for this clarification instead of answering.  In other words, only post an answer after the question has been clarified.  (Unfortunately, you don't yet have the privilege to comment on other users' posts -- so it would be better if you begin by only posting answers on questions that are sufficiently clear.)

Comment: And now I remember why I was put off Stack Overflow before... can't ask a question so can't help the person due to having no community reputation... it's hardly conducive to encouraging usage.

Comment: It is a small (self-protective) hurdle, but once you get a couple of upvotes (literally two -- just 15 points or more) then you are perceived as a real human / non-threat to the system and things start to open up as a matter of trust.  Answer a few more questions which are clearly asked where you are confident of your insights and you will be off and running.

Comment: Ok, no worries @mickmackusa I will keep that in mind and look out for a couple of those... it's definitely a Yootheme template though :-)

Comment: In that case, if this answer resolves the question and the OP accepts your answer, you will earn 15 points in one shot.